# Combining parent details requests in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-java

I have a list of objects of class A that I get from a server. This class A contains, among other items, a list of IDs. These IDs are then used to retrieve a list of objects of class B.

I have functions that return

```
Observable<List<A>>
```

and

```
Observable<B>
```

in place.

I would like to use RxJava to retrieve the list of A objects, then retrieve the list of B objects for each A object, and assign the B objects to the A object they belong to, so I would like to end up with a List of some composite object similar to this:

```
class Details {
    public A a;
    public List<B> listOfB;
}
```

and return

```
Observable<List<Details>>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, as you described, you have the functions:

```
Observable<List<A>> getAList()
```

and

```
Observable<B> getB(Long id)
```

Basically you need to make use of `Observable.from` method to decouple list to single elements and of course `Observable.flatMap` to transform `Observable`'s.

Create a helper function to get list of `B` from `A`'s list:

```
public Observable<List<B>> getBFromAList(List<Long> idList) {
    return Observable.from(idList)
            .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<B>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<B> call(Long id) {
                    return getB(id);
                }
            })
            .toList();
}
```

and the main function:

```
public Observable<List<Details>> getDetailsList() {
    return getAList()
            .flatMap(new Func1<List<A>, Observable<A>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<A> call(List<A> aList) {
                    return Observable.from(aList);
                }
            }).flatMap(new Func1<A, Observable<Details>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Details> call(A a) {
                    return getBFromAList(a.idList)
                            .zipWith(Observable.just(a), new Func2<List<B>, A, Details>() {
                                @Override
                                public Details call(List<B> bs, A a) {
                                    Details details = new Details();
                                    details.a = a;
                                    details.listOfB = bs;
                                    return details;
                                }
                            });
                }
            }).toList();

}
```